# Are LBA and CHS format for hard drive device or partition?

Tags: hard-drive

Are LBA and CHS format ways to address locations in a hard drive device or in a partition on it? In other words, are they independent of partition or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are an absolute location on the hard drive. Partitions begin at one of the locations given by the scheme (and with any luck, end at another one).